# Ruby String merge

Tags: ruby, string, merge

I would like to merge Strings in Ruby 1.8.7, please help.

```
s1 = "abc(1,,,,)"
s2 = "abc(,,3,,)"
s3 = "abc(,2,,,)"
s4 = "abc(,,,,5)"
```

and the output should be:

```
s = "abc(1,2,3,,5)"
```

Is there any in-built function available in Ruby 1.8.7 to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?  Possibly not generic enough...

```
def merge *strings
    result_array = strings.inject([]) do |merged_array,string|
        string_content = string[/\((.+?)\)/, 1].split(',', -1)
        string_content.each_with_index do |elem,idx|
            if !merged_array[idx] || merged_array[idx].empty?
                merged_array[idx] = elem 
            end
        end

        merged_array
    end

    $` + '(' + result_array.join(',') + ')' + $'
end

p merge(s1, s2, s3, s4) #=> "abc(1,2,3,,5)"
```